# URL for Settings>Privacy>Location Services in iOS 11+?

Tags: settings, ios11, openurl

If `locationServicesEnabled() == false`, I'm prompting the user to enable their Location Services. The following `URL` works for 10.0+, redirecting the user to the Settings app and directly to the Location Services screen:

```
URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION")
```

However this doesn't work in iOS 11. It opens the Settings app, but doesn't drill down to the Location Services. Anyone knows what's the new URL for iOS 11+?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: Did anybody get a work around ?

Comment: Still looking for a workaround. Can only open to main settings app with that URL :( I hope Apple still supports this :/

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue since the first `beta` releases. I've tested a lot of different `schemas` but none of them worked properly. In the first releases opening `schemas` would redirect to the home screen but they already fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Open Location Services:
If this app is for personal use only and you do not plan to submit it to the App Store, then you should be ok to use the following. Otherwise, if you do plan to release your app, Apple will reject it upon review. Code is:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "App-prefs:LOCATION_SERVICES")!)
```